# Elapsed time of SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

When I remove 41 and 42 lines, Elapsed time is "00:00:03.13". The "com_site" table aliased as [c] has no index or PK.
Result records count is 5503(20 records before removing.)
Could anyone explain me why this happens?
Thanks...

Comment: Best to tag properly -- that's PLSQL/Oracle code, not TSQL/SQL Server.  Posting code as an image also makes it difficult to read, much less edit because text can be resized in a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the alias [c] has no index, the conditions

```
c.site_gb LIKE 'A%'
c.up_dept_cd='A001'
```

can be processed first if [c] is small enough compared to the other tables.  Processing this first would be preferable to processing the correlated 2-level sub-query involving the tuple (bank_cd, acct_no).